# Do we need to denormalize model in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, denormalization

We usually store a graph of objects in databases. in rdbms, we need to male joins to retry the relationships between objects. In cassandra, it is promoted to denormalize model to fit the queries. But making this, we make the update of the model more complex or more specified.
In Cassandra, it exists complex data types like set, map, list ou tuples. These types make possible to store the relationships between object in a straitghforward manner (association, aggregation, composition of object) by storing inside for instance a list the ids of the connected objects.
The only drawback is then to have to divide a sql complex join request in several requests.
I ve not seen papers on cassandra dealing with this kind of solution. Has someone in mind the reason why this solution is not promoted?

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra is highly write optimized database. So writes are cheap, meaning an extra three or four writes will hardly matter considering the difficulties it would create if it were not otherwise.

Regarding graphs of objects, the answer is: No. Cassandra isn't meant to store graphs of objects. Cassandra is meant to store data for queries. The RDBMS equivalent would be views in PostgreSQL. Data has to be stored in a way that a query can be easily serviced. The main reason being that reads are slow. The goal of data modeling in Cassandra is to make sure a read is almost always from a single partition.

If it were normalized data, a query would need to hit a minimum of two partitions and worst case scenarios would create latencies that would render the application unusable for any practical purpose.

Hence data modeling in Cassandra is always centered on **queries** and not the *relationship* between objects.

More on these basic rules can be found in Datastax's documentation

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling